# Counting Conjugacy Classes: $A^6 = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

This question is inspired by [this earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892641/81360).  The question that I'm interested in is as follows:

> Let $S= \{A \in \mathbb{Q}^{k \times k} : A^6 = I \text{ and }A^n \ne I \text{ for any }0 < n < 6\}$. How many orbits under conjugation by $GL_k(\mathbb{Q})$ does $S$ contain?

Per the argument that I've given in the linked post, it suffices to list representatives in [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#General_case_and_theory).  Thus, it is equivalent to enumerate the multisets of irreducible polynomials $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ (which are the polynomials corresponding to companion matrix blocks) each of which divides $x^6-1$, whose degrees sum to $k$, and whose lcm divides $x^6 - 1$ but no polynomial of the form $x^n - 1$ for $n < 6$.

Of course, there is only one such multiset in the case of $k=2$, hence the answer to the linked question.  As $k$ grows things get trickier. For $k=5$, we have
$$
\{x^2 - x + 1, x \pm 1, x \pm 1, x\pm 1\}\\
\{x^2 + x + 1, x+1, x\pm 1, x\pm 1\}\\
\{x^2 - x + 1,  x^2 \pm x + 1 ,x \pm 1\}\\
\{x^2 + x + 1, x^2 + x + 1, x+1\}\\
$$
For a total of $14$ conjugacy classes.

How might one approach this problem in general?

Comment: @giannispapav I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but neither $x-1$ nor $x+1$ divides $x^2 - x + 1$.

Comment: For $k=5$, you can have two blocks with characteristic polynomial $x^2+x+1$, and one block with characteristic polynomial $x+1$, though.  The condition that $x^2-x+1$ divides the lcm is not true either.  This is why this problem is quite tricky.  And if you changed it to $A^m=I$ with $A^d\neq I$ for all proper divisors $d$ of $m$, then the problem becomes very difficult when $m$ has so many distinct prime divisors.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right. I'll delete my comment

Comment: @Batominovski updated, thanks for the corrections

Comment: I think this is true.  The matrix $A$ satisfies the condition iff, in some basis, $A$ has $s$ blocks with characteristic polynomials $\Phi_{d_1},\Phi_{d_2},\ldots,\Phi_{d_s}$, where $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s$ are divisors of $m$  such that $$\phi(d_1)+\phi(d_2)+\ldots+\phi(d_s)=k\text{ and }\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s)=m\,.$$  Here, $\Phi_d$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial, and $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  No idea how to count the tuples $(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s)$

Comment: @Batominovski I think the condition that $\Phi_6$ divides the lcm does hold. Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: I already gave a counterexample for $k=5$ and $m=6$, where there are two blocks for $\Phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1$ and one block for $\Phi_2(x)=x+1$.  So, $d_1=3$, $d_2=3$, and $d_3=2$.  We see that $$\phi(d_1)+\phi(d_2)+\phi(d_3)=2+2+1=5=k\text{ and }\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,d_3)=\text{lcm}(3,3,2)=6=m\,.$$  However, $\Phi_6$ is not a divisor of $\text{lcm}(\Phi_3,\Phi_3,\Phi_2)$.

Comment: @Batominovski of course; it seems that I miscalculated the lcm. Thanks for spelling it out.

Comment: Therefore, the number  of conjugacy classes for a given pair $(k,m)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is  $$\begin{align}N(k,m)&=\#\Big\{(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s)\in D_m^s\,\Big|\,s\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\,,\,\,d_1\geq d_2\geq \ldots\geq d_s\,,\,\,\\&\phantom{aaaaaaaaaa}\sum_{i=1}^s\,\phi(d_i)=k\,,\text{ and }\text{lcm}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s)=m\Big\}\,,\end{align}$$
where $D_m$ denotes the set of all positive integers dividing $m$.  But $N(k,m)$ seems very difficult to compute explicitly without help from computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read my comments under the OP's question.  In this answer, I would like to only address the case $m=6$, that is, the situation the OP asks for.  I do not know how to deal with the general exponent $m$.

As we have established, the characteristic polynomial involved in each indecomposable block of $A$ is one of the following four cyclotomic polynomials: $$\Phi_1(x)=x-1\,,\,\,\Phi_2(x)=x+1\,,\,\,\Phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1\,,\text{ and }\Phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1\,.$$ Now, $A$ must have at least one indecomposable block of size $2\times 2$.  Let $a$ and $b$ denote the number of $2$-by-$2$ indecomposable blocks of $A$ and the number of $1$-by-$1$ blocks of $A$.  Then, $a\geq 1$ and $2a+b=k$. Denote by $J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_a$ the $2$-by-$2$ blocks of $A$, whereas $K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_b$ the $1$-by-$1$ blocks.  We may assume that $J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_p$ have $\Phi_6$ as the characteristic polynomial, whereas $J_{p+1},J_{p+2},\ldots,J_a$ have $\Phi_3$ as the characteristic polynomial.  Similarly, suppose that $K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_q$ have $\Phi_2$ as the characteristic polynomial, whilst $K_{q+1},K_{q+2},\ldots,K_b$ have $\Phi_1$ as the characteristic polynomial.

If $p\geq 1$, then there is no restriction on $q$.  Thus, for each fixed $a\in\Biggl\{1,2,\ldots,\left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\Biggr\}$, there are $a$ ways to choose $p\geq 1$ and $b+1=k-2a+1$ ways to choose $q$.  Thus, for $p\geq 1$, there are
$$\begin{align}\sum_{a=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor}\,a(k-2a+1)&=(k-1)\,\sum_{a=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor}\,a-4\,\sum_{a=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor}\,\frac{a(a-1)}{2}
\\
&=\frac{k-1}{2}\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\,\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)-\frac{2}{3}\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\,\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)\,\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor-1\right)
\end{align}$$
corresponding conjugacy classes.

If $b=0$, then $q\geq1$ is required.  Thus, for each fixed $a\in\Biggl\{1,2,\ldots,\left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\Biggr\}$, there are $b=k-2a$ ways to choose $q\geq 1$.  Hence, for $p=0$, there are
$$\sum_{a=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor}\,(k-2a)=k\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\,\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)$$
corresponding conjugacy classes.

This shows that
$$N(k,6)=\frac{1}{6}\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\,\left(3\,(k-3)\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor-4\,\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor^2+9\,k-5\right)$$
is the total number of conjugacy classes.  We have
$$N(1,6)=0\,,\,\,N(2,6)=1\,,\,\,N(3,6)=3\,,\,\,N(4,6)=7\,,\text{ and }N(5,6)=12\,.$$
(The OP miscounted something.  From his list, there should be $12$ distinct conjugacy classes for $k=5$.)

Note that
$$\frac{(k-1)(k^2+10k-3)}{24}\leq N(k,6)\leq \frac{k(k-1)(k+10)}{24}\,.$$
The left-hand side is an equality iff $k$ is an odd positive integer.  The right-hand side is an equality iff $k=1$ or $k$ is an even positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q}),A^6=I$, then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ and its eigenvalues must be chosen among $1,-1$ or the couples $(j,j^2)$ or $(-j,-j^2)$ where $j=e^{2i\pi/3}$. Since the minimal polynomials of the above eigenvalues in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ have degree $2$, our matrices are classified by the eligible sequences with elements in the box $ 1, -1, (j, j ^ 2), (- j, -j ^ 2) $, elements encoded by $(1,2,3,4)$, ordered by $1\leq 2\leq 3\leq 4$ with $length(1)=length(2)=1,length(3)=length(4)=2$. One condition is $\sum_i length(i)=k$.

EDIT. The other condition is $order(A)=6$, that is, EITHER the element $4$ is in the considered sequence OR the couple $2,3$ is in the sequence.

Note that the number of similar classes is the same as in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

For example, when $k=4$, there are $7$ eligible sequences (then $7$ similar classes)
[1, 1, 4][1, 2, 3][1, 2, 4]                          [2, 2, 3][2, 2, 4][3, 4]                             [4, 4]

A rudimentary procedure (with computer) gives explicitly the list of the similarity classes and, of course, the number of classes.

For $k=5$, there are $12$ similar classes. 
[1, 1, 1, 4][1, 1, 2, 3][1, 1, 2, 4]                          [1, 2, 2, 3][1, 2, 2, 4][1, 3, 4]                           [1, 4, 4][2, 2, 2, 3][2, 2, 2, 4]                           [2, 3, 3][2, 3, 4][2, 4, 4]

For $k=6$, $20$ classes.

For $k=7$, $29$ classes.

These results are consistent with the counting Batominovski's formula (thanks to him for pointing out an error in the previous version of my post).

Comment: For $k=4$, you are missing the sequences $[1,2,3]$ and $[2,2,3]$.  For $k=5$, you are missing $[1,1,2,3]$, $[1,2,2,3]$, $[2,2,2,3]$, and $[2,3,3]$.

Comment: @Batominovski  , you are right; I wrote too fast; my condition for $order(A)=6$ is not correct. I go to edit.